How to Play Video in External Player (like MXPlayer) in React Native?
I'm new to React Native and I'm looking to play a video in an external player (such as MXPlayer) on both Android. I've searched online but haven't found a clear solution.
In Android, this can typically be done using Intents, but I'm not sure how to achieve the same functionality in React Native.
Here's what I'm looking to do:
. Open a video link in an external video player like MXPlayer.
Thank you in advance!
                              .                                                                                                                                         


Are you playing local videos or video URLs?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@JatinBhuva how to do so with urls, specifically m3u8
